# Is the completion of an infinitely generated module, again infinitely generated

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, completion

Let $A$ be a local noetherian ring with maximal ideal $m$. Let $M$ be an infinitely generated $A$-module and $\hat{M}$ be the $m$-adic completion of $M$. Denote by $\hat{A}$ the $m$-adic completion of $A$. Recall, $\hat{M}$ is an $\hat{A}$-module. My question is: Is $\hat{M}$ infinitely generated as an $\hat{A}$-module?

**EDIT** Assume that the annihilator of $M$ *properly* contains the zero prime ideal (the prime ideal containing $0$) and there does not exist an integer $n$ such that $m^n$ is contained in the annihilator of $M$.

Comment: The $\frak m$-adic completion could even be 0 (for example, when $A$ is domain and $M$ is its fraction field).

Comment: @Angelo Thank you. I have edited the question slightly with an additional condition on the support.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb Z_p$ as a module over $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$. It is infinitely (even uncountably) generated for cardinality reason, but taking the completions we get $\mathbb Z_p$ over $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Your edited condition does not help: take the fraction field of $A/\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is any prime ideal strictly contained in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Completing a module that is not finitely generated is often very bad for its health. That's why derived completion (a gentler kind of completion) was invented (just do a google search).